# How to pass JSON with @ symbol to props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am requesting json data from a db using axios with react. I am able to get the json and assign it to state and pass it as props to child components in my app. The problem I am having is that some of the objects in the json begin with an '@' symbol and throw a syntax error.

```
    var Events = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      events: [],
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios
        .get("MY URL STRING HERE")
        .then(function(result) {
          _this.setState({
            events: result.data
          });
        })
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.events.map(function(event) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <Event title={event.EventTitle} date={event.EventDate} description={event.EventDescription} presentor={event.EventPresenters} location={event.EventLocation} registered={event.registeredusercount} max_reg={event.EventMaximumAttendees} key={event.@unid} id={key} status={event.status} />
                        </div>
                    ) 
                })};
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI, your problem has nothing to do with JSON. The data is already parsed, so your problem is with a JavaScript object containing `@` in one of its properties. The problem is not specific to React either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your issue isn't with parsing the data, but with React passing the objects down as props? If so, you should be able to access the attributes via string dynamically [with bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), like so.

```
let foo = {'@bar': 'test'};
foo.@bar;
// => Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

foo['@bar'];
// => 'test'
```

For your component, it would be:

```
<Event key={event['@unid']} />
```